# Cannot add Libre Office Start Center to Favourites?

Tags: libreoffice, gnome-shell

I have been having this weird issue with Ubuntu-based distros that I cannot add the Libre office start menu to either my desktop or to the favourites. I can barely find it via the dash and when I right-click it, there are no options whatsoever? I hope I am making sense. If I travel to /usr/share/applications I can launch the start centre from there. If I move it to my desktop (Pop!_OS) it will show in my ~/Desktop folder, but does not actually appear there visibly. It is really weird.

Comment: What happens if you type `libreoffice` in a terminal? And how did you install Libre Office? If you type `sudo apt install libreoffice`, what is the message you get back?

Comment: What is your version of ubuntu and pop os ?

Comment: I have found the answer--@vanadium gave it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Copy the .desktop file of the control center, `/usr/share/applications/libreoffice-startcenter.desktop` to your local `~/.local/share/applications` folder. Change the line `NotShowIn=GNOME;` to `NotShowIn=`, or delete the line. The launcher will now be found in your dash. You can launch it and then right-click the icon in your dash to pin it.

Some background: the line `NotShowIn=GNOME;` prevents the launcher from actually showing up in the dash. While you can edit the system wide desktop file, it is safer practice to copy the .desktop file locally and edit it there. You do not need root permissions for that, and your changes will not be overwritten by future updates. You can edit the system wide file if you want the change to be effective for all users on the system.

Comment: Thank you! That is so weird that they would remove that for the gnome version... but I guess it may mess with the ideal workflow of Gnome? IDK, still weird.

Comment: It is a personal taste, I guess. I for myself prefer the center to be hidden, but at least this is Linux, so you can tweak things.

Comment: I find it easier to navigate, but odds are, I am either opening a document I have been working on in Writer or in Calc, and I divide things int folders and folders of folders. Or I am going to be starting a new document, which would require, for me, either a book template or a script template, so, lol. Plus, then I don't have to have more than one icon on my desktop or in my favourites.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding LibreOffice 7.3, I found the entry `NoDisplay=true` at the beginning (Fedora36, line 22) in `/usr/share/applications/libreoffice-startcenter.desktop`. I then copied the file as suggested to `~/.local/share/applications` and changed that to `NoDisplay=false`. That worked fine for me on Fedora 36, but also on Ubuntu 22.04 (Installation not from the repos, but directly from the *.debs at de.libreoffice.org) and on SuSE Leap 15.4. There is no entry `NotShowIn=Gnome` anymore in all of the files.